# Import file using modin: CancelledError: lambda-cc7c2f3d406305cdaff20d8fae03d85b

Tags: pandas, modin

I faced a issue when try to import file using modin. I already install all package needed like pip install modin, pip install modin[all]

```
import modin.pandas as mpd
import time

start_time = time.time()
df_modin = mpd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\<my name>\Downloads\Parking_Violations_Issued_-_Fiscal_Year_2017.csv")
end_time = time.time()

print(f"Modin read time: {end_time - start_time} seconds")
```

Error:

```
CancelledError: lambda-cc7c2f3d406305cdaff20d8fae03d85b
```

The csv file indeed very large, about 2GB. It's might be file are too large, and take long time so it cancelled by modin?

I'm using local VSCode and not run in any cloud such as github codespace.

And I do look up someone else code, code is same but mine just won't run(I already sucessfully import file use pandas and dask).
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdlLk.png)
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcvmd.png)

Already present in problem section
Expect import file use modin sucessfully

Comment: Can you provide the CSV file (e.g. as a gist on GitHub) or another one that causes the same error so others can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your response, this problem has already been solved. I just create a new notebook with same code/csv, and it run.  I don't know why

Comment: Ok, consider deleting your question since it is not reproducible and therefore not likely to help future readers.